# Need help creating deeplinks / dynamic links for a swift app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

can someone help me with universal links / deep links using swift?

I have a hybrid webapp(its an app with a webview) and want to direct the user to a particular page using deeplinks.. How can I do this?

For example: 
if the link is sample://login?activ=xyz
It should open the app "sample" and load https://www.sample.com/login?activ=xyz
thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your url in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options`

Here you can edit your request.

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you know of any samples that show how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Your Question is really unclear. But if you mean you have a link and want to insert parameters, you can do it with String-Manipulation